# Xamarin - Observablecollections entre 3 forms

Tags: xamarin, listview

Tenho um aplicativo em desenvolvimento com um problema sério na passagem de dados de uma tela pra outra.
Quando comecei, fiz uma tela inicial com um listview, nele eu tinha uma searchbox onde o usuário digitava uma descrição breve de um veículo e ao clicar no botão buscar, o sistema retornava os dados, acionando o icommand, fazendo com que uma viewmodel processasse os dados e pelo observablecollection mostrava no listview.
Agora tive que implementar uma tela de pesquisa avançada, ainda não coloquei nenhum código pra filtro nela, apenas coloquei o botão buscar que executa o mesmo icommand, quanto faço um debug, a variável que recebe a lista de dados está populada, porém o listview continua sem nada.

Estou quase entrando em desespero por causa disso, meu conhecimento de C# é mínimo, e sou novo no Visual Studio, pra piorar.

Caso, alguém consiga me ajudar, agradeço.

Segue a primeira tela

```
namespace TvCar.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class PesquisaDetalhada : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public PesquisaDetalhada()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BindingContext = new ViewModels.Veiculo_ViewModel();            

        string img_condicao, img_marca, img_modelo, img_ano, img_versao, img_preco, img_km, img_cambio, img_combustivel, img_portas, img_cor, img_cidade;

        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                img_condicao    = "img_condicao.png";
                img_marca       = "img_marca.png";
                img_modelo      = "img_modelo.png";
                img_ano         = "img_ano.png";
                img_versao      = "img_versao.png";
                img_preco       = "img_preco.png";
                img_km          = "img_km.png";
                img_cambio      = "img_cambio.png";
                img_combustivel = "img_combustivel.png";
                img_portas      = "img_portas.png";
                img_cor         = "img_cor.png";
                img_cidade      = "img_cidade.png";
                break;

            case Device.Android:
            default:
                img_condicao = "img_condicao.png";
                img_marca = "img_marca.png";
                img_modelo = "img_modelo.png";
                img_ano = "img_ano.png";
                img_versao = "img_versao.png";
                img_preco = "img_preco.png";
                img_km = "img_km.png";
                img_cambio = "img_cambio.png";
                img_combustivel = "img_combustivel.png";
                img_portas = "img_portas.png";
                img_cor = "img_cor.png";
                img_cidade = "img_cidade.png";
                break;
        }

        listView.ItemsSource = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Name = "Condição",Image = img_condicao} ,
            new Item {Name = "Marca",Image = img_marca} ,
            new Item {Name = "Modelo",Image = img_modelo},
            new Item {Name = "Ano",Image = img_ano},
            new Item {Name = "Versão",Image = img_versao},
            new Item {Name = "Preço",Image = img_preco},
            new Item {Name = "KM",Image = img_km},
            new Item {Name = "Cambio",Image = img_cambio},
            new Item {Name = "Combustível",Image = img_combustivel},
            new Item {Name = "Portas",Image = img_portas},
            new Item {Name = "Cor",Image = img_cor},
            new Item {Name = "Cidade",Image = img_cidade}
        };
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.ListarAnuncios());
    }

    class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Segue a segunda tela (Listview)

```
namespace TvCar.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ListarAnuncios : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ListarAnuncios()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        this.Detalhes.ItemsSource = null;
        this.Detalhes.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<ViewModels.Veiculo_ViewModel>();

        this.Detalhes.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            var detalhe = e.Item as Model.Veiculo_Cadastro;
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.VeiculoDetalhes(detalhe));

            MainPage.mcodveiculo = detalhe.VEICULO_CODIGO;
            MainPage.mDesVeiculo = detalhe.VEICULO_DESCRICAO;
            MainPage.Atualiza_Visitas(sender: PropertyChanged);
        };
    }

    internal static ListView Listarlv;

    //private void OnTextChanged()
    //{
    //    MainPage.DadosBusca = string.Concat("AND UPPER(A.VEICULO_VERSAO) LIKE UPPER('%", Pesquisar.Text, "%') ");
    //}

    public class StringCaseConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            string param = System.Convert.ToString(parameter) ?? "u";

            switch (param.ToUpper())
            {
                case "U":
                    return ((string)value).ToUpper();
                case "L":
                    return ((string)value).ToLower();
                default:
                    return ((string)value);
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public VeiculoDetalhes Selecao_Item { get; set; }
}
```

Segue a classe que faz a busca dos dados

```
namespace TvCar.ViewModels
{
public sealed class Veiculo_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged // classe
{
    public ICommand CarregarCommand { get; set; }
    public VeiculoDetalhes Selecao_Item { get; set; }        

    private ObservableCollection<Model.Veiculo_Cadastro> Anuncio;
    public ObservableCollection<Model.Veiculo_Cadastro> Anuncios
    {
        get { return Anuncio; }
        set
        {
            Anuncio = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Anuncios)));
        }
    }

    public Veiculo_ViewModel()
    {
        CarregarCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(async () =>
        {
            var Anuncio = await ApiAnuncios.Api_Rest.GetAsync();
            Anuncios = new ObservableCollection<Model.Veiculo_Cadastro>(Anuncio);


            TvCar.MainPage.MinhaLista = new ListView();
            TvCar.MainPage.MinhaLista.ItemsSource = null;
            TvCar.MainPage.MinhaLista.ItemsSource = Anuncios;
        });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Sem os códigos para saber exatamente onde está o problema fica difícil ajudar. Seria legal postar sim.

Comment: Então, Gustavo, aqui segue as telas. Usando a tela do listview, com um searchbar, o icommand da classe veiculo_viewmodel é acionado e retorna os dados no listview.
Quando clico no botão buscar da tela ListarAnuncios, ele também aciona o icommand da classe veiculo_viewmodel é acionado, a variável Anuncios é carregada com os dados, porém o listview não recebe dados.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, depois de bater muito a cabeça, acabei descobrindo uma solução, talvez não seja a ideal, mas funcionou para mim. Fiz as seguintes modificações:
Na minha MainPage.cs criei uma listview estática assim:
public static ListView MinhaLista = null;

Dentro da Veiculo_ViewModel
Antes -------------->
public Veiculo_ViewModel()
        {
            CarregarCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(async () =>
            {
                var Anuncio = await ApiAnuncios.Api_Rest.GetAsync();
                Anuncios = new ObservableCollection(Anuncio);
            });
        }

Agora ------------>
public Veiculo_ViewModel()
        {
            CarregarCommand = new Xamarin.Forms.Command(async () =>
            {
                var Anuncio = await ApiAnuncios.Api_Rest.GetAsync();
                Anuncios = new ObservableCollection(Anuncio);

```
            MainPage.MinhaLista = new ListView();
            MainPage.MinhaLista.ItemsSource = Anuncios;
        });
    }
```

Dentro do ListarAnuncios.cs
Antes ------>
this.Detalhes.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection();

Agora ------->
this.Detalhes.ItemsSource = MainPage.MinhaLista.ItemsSource;

Dentro do ListarAnuncios.xaml
Antes ---------->

Agora ----------->

Dentro do PesquisaDetalhada.cs
Antes ----------------->
        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.ListarAnuncios());
        }

Agora -------------->
        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CarregaItens();
        }

```
    public async Task CarregaItens()
    {
        var xAnuncio = new ViewModels.Veiculo_ViewModel();
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Views.ListarAnuncios());
    }
```

Ae, funcionou maravilhosamente.
Fica ae a dica.